# Assignment from one instance variable to another on the same instance by value in Python?

Tags: python, variables

```
//pseudo-code
class animshape(object):

    def __init__(self,position):
        self.position= position


    def startupdate(self):
        self.startPosition = self.position //I want to get the value 
                          //of self.position only when startupdate is called
        self.animate()

    def animate:
        self.position += 1 //alter the value of self.position
```

In my actual code position is a Vector2 type, using the pyEuclid library.

I would like to set the variable self.startPosition = self.position only when startupdate is called.  What occurs now is that startPosition changes whenever position is altered, this makes sense to me. But is there a mechanism in python for the behavior I want?

Comment: this question makes no sense...

Comment: what type is position?  If it is a list or some object and you are changing the state of that object, then that makes sense, because startPosition and position are pointing to the same object.

Comment: You'll want to make a copy of your Vector2 and store that in startPosition in the startupdate method.

Comment: I see now copy.deepcopy() and copy().  Thank You.

Comment: if i understand correctly then you need to define a new variable in __init__ : self.sposition = position and assign that self.sposition to self.startposition.